# Prove that if, for the vectors $u$, $v$, and $w$, $u + v + w = 0$ then $u \times v = v \times w = w \times u$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am asked to prove that if, for the vectors $u$, $v$, and $w$, $u + v + w = 0$ then $u \times v = v \times w = w \times u$; however, I'm a little stumped on this question. I started by expanding out each cross product in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and then associating each of the 3 terms for the each of the 3 cross products. But I don't notice any pattern or relation to the first sum. How might I go about proving this?

Comment: Hint: cross $u+v+w$ with $v$ and use $v\times v=0\,.$

Comment: Hint: replace $w$ by $-u-v$ in $v\times w$ and in $w\times u,$ and use that $\times$ is bilinear and alternating.